# Pandas group by without losing type information while ensuring all data is retained

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using this function to group a pandas dataframe. I have a frame with float64, int64, and object columns. This function groupbyFlatCount is adapted from dask. I was encountering issues with missing data when grouping over an int64 column. I isolated this column and was able to get it to work with an object dtype.

```
def groupbyFlatCount(frame, by):
    return  frame.groupby(by=by).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

How can I get this function to work without losing type information?

Answer (score 0):

The robust solution to this issue is to convert to object columns and then back again.

```
def groupbyFlatCount(frame, by):
dtypes = frame[by].dtypes.to_dict()
for col in by:
    frame[col] = frame[col].map(str)
return  frame.groupby(by=by).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'}).astype(dtypes)
```